# Scrape table data from website python beautiful soup - Access all table entries

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried to access the table data while scraping the FDA website.

https://www.fda.gov/inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/compliance-actions-and-activities/warning-letters

While scraping the above link, I am getting only 10 entries of the table. But there are around 2500 entries in the table. Inspected the website by using F12 key but that gives me 10 entries even after changing the "Show entries to 50"

[image]

I want to use Python beautiful Soup to access all the entries of the table. How can I do that?

Comment: You'll need to either recreate the requests the website is making with Javascript to load additional entries, or automate the website using a tool like Selenium to let the browser do that work for you.

Comment: Requests doesn't support JavaScript. Your best bet is to use beautiful soup in conjunction with Selenium and a web driver (Firefox/Chrome etc). You can run the browser headless to mimic Requests. But the Requests response body isn't even going to see those pagination button links. All it's going to see is the "#".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure Beautiful Soup supports this, but you need to load the table rows by scrolling the page.
This can be done with Selenium:
Read the initially loaded data, scroll the page up, read the currently presented data and so on until the page bottom is presented.